# how to convert python to msi

Tags: python, export, windows-installer, cx-freeze

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

company_name = 'AI Production'
product_name = 'AI'

bdist_msi_options = {
    'upgrade_code': '{66620F3A-DC3A-11E2-B341-002219E9B01E}',
    'add_to_path': False,
    'initial_target_dir': r'[ProgramFilesFolder]\%s\%s' % (company_name, product_name),
    }

build_exe_options = {"bdist_msi":{"packages":["tkinter", "tkcalendar", "PIL", "random", "speech_recognition", "time", "sqlite3", 
                                            "pyttsx3", "threading", "datetime", "AppOpener", "wave", "pyaudio", "wikipedia", "requests",
                                            "numpy", "cv2", "autocorrect", "pyautogui", "webbrowser", 'bs4', 'GoogleNews',
                                            'winsound', 'pywhatkit'],
                    "include_files":['Animation/bow_animation.gif', 'Animation/hand_waving_animation.gif', 
                                    'Animation/idle_animation.gif', 'Animation/logo_animation.gif',
                                    'Animation/start_walking_animation.gif', 'database/text.txt',
                                    'document/text.txt', 'icons/desktop.ico', 'icons/logo.ico',
                                    'icons/mic_off.ico', 'icons/mic.ico', 'icons/person.ico',
                                    'icons/save.ico', 'icons/sending icon.ico', 'icons/setting_icon.ico',
                                    'icons/user.ico', 'Image/bg.png', 'Image/bg/color_circle_deb3e0.png',
                                    'Image/bg/color_pallet_212b2a.png', 'Image/bg/color_pallet_custom.png',
                                    'Image/bg/color_pallet_404a4c.png', 'Image/bg/color_pallet_d6e6ff.png',
                                    'Image/bg/color_pallet_d7f9f8.png', 'Image/bg/color_pallet_e5d4ef.png',
                                    'Image/bg/color_pallet_f9d7f8.png', 'Image/bg/color_pallet_fbb8ed.png',
                                    'Image/bg/color_pallet_fbe0e0.png', 'Image/gr.png', 'voice/mic_starter.mp3',
                                    'voice/timer_alarm.wav']},
    }

base = 'Win32GUI'

exe = Executable(script='AI.pyw',
                 base=base,
                 icon='icons\logo.ico',
                )

setup(name=product_name,
      version='1.0.0',
      description='blah',
      executables=[exe],
      options={
          'bdist_msi': bdist_msi_options,
          'build_exe': build_exe_options})
```

I tried this code to generate msi for my program and I generate one using cx_freeze. But when I install it, I cannot run my application. and I can't find the error in my code. I can't find it in menu or anywhere else but it shows on control panel

Answer (score 0):

Have you tryied to run the executable file in cmd? Usually when I have this problem, running on cmd helps to identify the error.

It is probably a dependency package that is not recognized in the built project, it happens a lot. But check in cmd to see exactly the error.